# How to pick up and sort more efficiently in R?

Tags: r, sorting, for-loop, time-complexity

I have a matrix `a`comprising 9 columns and 16 million rows in R. Each element in the 4th column is either "Apple" or "Lion".

I want to collect those rows having the entry "Apple" in their 4th column, together, and sort this "new" matrix with respect to integer entries in the first column.

What is the best way to perform this? The output will be a .csv file, of course, as it is impossible to view this matrix in R (16 million rows!!).

I tried two codes:

1) In this code, I first introduce a 9-dimensional vector `b` having all zeroes. Then I run a `for` loop that checks whether in each row of `a`, the fourth element is "Apple". If so, that row is added to `b`, and in this way, `b` grows. Finally I sort `b` using the order function.

```
b=rep(0,9)
   for(i in 1:nrow(a)){
   if(a[i,4]=="Apple"){
      b=rbind(b,a[i,])
   }
}
b=order(b)
write.table(b,"Apple.csv",sep=",",append=TRUE,col.names=FALSE)
```

This code does not seem to work as it is taking too long to run the for loop only!!

2) I run a for loop which checks whether the fourth entry of each row in `a` is "Apple". If so, it prints that row to a .csv file. So no matrix is created in R. This .csv file will be read into R after completion and after converting the first column by `as.integer` function to integer entries, I sort the table using `order` function.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(a)){
   if(a[i,4]=="Apple"){
      write.table(a[i,],"Apple.csv",sep=",",append=TRUE,col.names=FALSE)
   }
}

a=read.csv("Apple.csv")
a[,1]=as.integer(a[,1])
a=order(a)
```

This seems to work, although very slowly on my laptop. At the rate it is going, the for loop will take 5 days to complete, apparently. I don't know whether my laptop, having 4 GB RAM is intrinsically unable to work with such huge data-sets.

In what ways can I optimize the code? What will be the most efficient code for this procedure? I will be glad if someone points me in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an alternative answer using another popular package called `data.table`. DT is like data frame, but on steroids, more close in design to the SQL

```
library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(matrix(data = NA, nrow = 20000000, ncol = 9))
DT$V4 <- sample(c("Apple","Lion"), size = 20000000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5, 0.5) )
DT$V9 <- rnorm(20000000, mean = 0, sd = 1000)

str(DT)

setkey(DT, V9)

system.time( r <- setorder( DT[V4 == "Apple"], V9 ) )
str(r)

tables()
```

On my laptop it took

```
user  system elapsed
2.35    0.30    2.64
```

Memory use

```
     NAME       NROW NCOL  MB COLS                       KEY
[1,] DT   20,000,000    9 916 V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9 V9
[2,] r     9,998,016    9 420 V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9 V9
Total: 1,336MB
```

Link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html
Cheat-Sheet: http://blog.datacamp.com/data-table-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 6):

You should try to use some of the data wrangling packages in R that are designed for this type of work. They execute extremely efficiently. Below I use the `dplyr` package.

I first create a data frame of 20,000,000 rows and 9 columns. I then set column 4 to be either `Apple` or `Lion` randomly. I then set column 9 to be randomly chosen from a normal distribution centered at 0 with a large standard deviation  (so that the numbers are more or less far apart).

I can filter for Apple and sort the remaining data frame in under 10 seconds. Below is the code.

```
> library(dplyr)
> 
> myDF <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = NA, nrow = 20000000, ncol = 9))
> myDF$V4 <- sample(c("Apple","Lion"), size = 20000000, replace=  TRUE, prob = c(0.5, 0.5) )
> myDF$V9 <- rnorm(20000000, mean = 0, sd = 1000)
> 
> system.time(AppleOnlySorted <- myDF %>%
+   filter(V4 == "Apple") %>%
+   arrange(V9))
   user  system elapsed 
  9.165   0.140   9.306 
> 
> head(AppleOnlySorted)
  V1 V2 V3    V4 V5 V6 V7 V8        V9
1 NA NA NA Apple NA NA NA NA -5053.535
2 NA NA NA Apple NA NA NA NA -4947.533
3 NA NA NA Apple NA NA NA NA -4853.408
4 NA NA NA Apple NA NA NA NA -4848.063
5 NA NA NA Apple NA NA NA NA -4838.298
6 NA NA NA Apple NA NA NA NA -4824.169
> 
> system.time(AppleOnlySortedDescending <- myDF %>%
+               filter(V4 == "Apple") %>%
+               arrange(desc(V9)))
   user  system elapsed 
  8.948   0.134   9.083
```

I've wrapped the commands in a `system.time` to show how fast it is, but the output is saved in `AppleOnlySorted` and `AppleOnlySortedDescending`. You can then save that data frame to a csv or whatever format you want.

Looking at the size of `myDF` it's only 839.2 Mb. So assuming you're RAM is not loaded with a bunch of memory hogs -- it should be ok.

```
> format(object.size(myDF), units = "Mb")
[1] "839.2 Mb"
```

Worst comes to worst, you can always look at using the `bigmemory` package to write stuff out to disk -- but I doubt you'll need that for this operation.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'll definitely use this code! Thank you, I had no idea this package existed! Frankly, this is my first venture into large data, earlier what we've done is basically introductory things in R.

Comment: @LandonCarter: if you like the answer, please mark this question as answered by clicking the check mark next to it. Thanks!